# How do I access an array inside another array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I access the values ​​that the associative array brings in "version" separately? I mean, I want to be able to bring v1, v2 and v3 separately to use them.

```
<?php

$version = array("v1", "v2", "v3");

$newarray = array("value1" => "Value 1",
                    "value2" => "Value 2",
                    "version" => implode($version));
```

I understand that with a foreach it is possible, but I do not know how. And on the other hand, I do not know if it's the best way to assign that array "version" with implode

Answer (score 1):

Implode has no use in this example.

```
<?php

$version = array("v1", "v2", "v3");

$newarray = array("value1" => "Value 1",
                    "value2" => "Value 2",
                    "version" => $version);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newarray);
echo '</pre>';

foreach ($newarray["version"] as $key => $value) {
    print '<br /> key: ' . $key . '  value: ' . $value;
}
```

Comment: may I ask how to do if I want to add another array inside `version` in `$newarray = array("value1" => "Value 1",
                    "value2" => "Value 2",
                    "version" => $version);` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach($key as $value), when $key equals "version" and do another "for loop" or when $value is type of array, do another "for loop".

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you look at your arrays in this way it will help :

```
$version['0'] = 'v1';
$version['1'] = 'v2';
$version['2'] = 'v3';
$newarray['value1'] = 'Value 1';
$newarray['value2'] = 'Value 2';
$newarray['version']['0'] = 'v1';
$newarray['version']['1'] = 'v2';
$newarray['version']['2'] = 'v3';
```

so to use foreach on version array , the one inside $newarray :

```
foreach ($newarray['version'] as $key=>$value) {
     // Do something 
}
```